# Jenkins Pipeline - Kickoff from slave

Tags: jenkins, bitbucket, jenkins-pipeline

My jenkins 2 instance connects to the internet (to download plugins etc., via proxy). I'm trying to setup a pipeline job - using pipeline script from Scm where the SCM is bitbucket (git). Now the issue is the job fails with a

```
returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: fatal: unable to access 'http://<ip>/repo.git/': The requested 
URL returned error: 403
```

I think this might be due to the proxy. I tried making the number of executors to 0 on the master, but still the job runs from the master. Is there a way/workaround by which I can make the slave responsible for kicking off the job?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep - it's the proxy (just ran into this).  Put the git server in the list of url prefixes to ignore.